# button click does not change the textview value

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

This is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Your total is 0"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

This is the java code:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;

            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;

            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    return true;
}

}
```

When I press the buttons nothing happens to the textview text at all.

Please help. I want the display to show the value of the counter after adding or subtracting depending on which button has been pressed.

Comment: Are you getting any crashes ? If not I believe your onCreateOptionsMenu function is not getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've placed your code in wrong place. You're not handling here with menu so you don't need to place your in `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}` the button won't get any action/fire

move  this

```
counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;

            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;

            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });
```

to your onCreate() method and try to run it again

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM:**

The android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) itself says that one is supposed to use `findViewById` in onCreate itself:

> onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most
>   importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a
>   layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to
>   retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with
>   programmatically.

But you are using them in CreateOptionsMenu.Perform these steps:

At first make these declarations class level:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int counter;
  Button add, sub;
 TextView display;
//......more code below
```

Move this piece of code to your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {` instead of `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {`. especially the counter code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //assigning initial value to counter

 counter = 0;//counter set

//getting the controls

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

//setting Listeners

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter++;

        display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
    }
});

sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter--;

        display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that.If my answer helped solve your problem,mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;

                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;

                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });

    }

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to put your code in oncreate method rather than onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Can you explain ? much interested for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Do All the stuff in onCreate method not in onCreateOptionsMenu as mentioned below

// below code

```
int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

counter = 0;
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter++;

        display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
    }
});

sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter--;

        display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
    }
});


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

return true;
}

}
```

Comment: why it needs to call getMenuInflater() in the onCreate() method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do your task within the onCreate method. The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) method is used for the perpose of task in the Option Menu. So replace your code within the onCreate Method.
The complete code is given below. Replace it and have a try. Hopefully it will work :)

```
      package com.example.helloworld;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
   add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
   display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter++;

        display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
    }
});

sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        counter--;

        display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
    }
});
}



     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


       return true;
   }

  }
```